# Enum with Sealed class with MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Please check below code:

```
sealed interface ResourceV2<out T> {

enum class Status {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR,
    LOADING
}

data class Success<T>(val data: T, val message: String, val code: Int, val state: Boolean) : ResourceV2<T>

data class Error<T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String, val code: Int, val state: Boolean) : ResourceV2<T>

data class Loading<T>(val state: Boolean) : ResourceV2<T>
```

}

---

And accessing in view like this:

```
Resource.Status.SUCCESS
```

[image]

I feel that ENUM should not used and there should be some other way to do clean MVVM architecture. Please suggest an answer and include how my Resource class should look like and how can I access it in view.

**OLDER Resource class:**

```
data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?, val code: Int, val state: Boolean) {

    enum class Status {
        SUCCESS,
        ERROR,
        LOADING
    }

    companion object {
        fun <T> success(data: T, message: String, code: Int, state: Boolean): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.SUCCESS, data, message, code, state)
        }

        fun <T> error(data: T? = null, message: String, code: Int, state: Boolean): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.ERROR, data, message, code, state)
        }

        fun <T> loading(state: Boolean): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.LOADING, null, null, NetworkConstant.NetworkValues.DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE, state)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the enum.  You can just cast check.

when (resource){
is Success -> print (${success.data})
is Error ->
is Loading ->
}

Comment: @GregoryNowik Please check the edited question and request you to provide an answer, I'm not getting compiler error is coming

Comment: You do not need `Enum` in fact that's the reason we r using a sealed and data classes here ..
You do not have to check for `it.status` because its does not exists .. Just check `is Success` or `is Error` . in the screenshot you have `Resource` but in the code example you have created `ResourceV2`.. this is confusing

Comment: Please consider as same @ADM

Answer (score 0):

This is how your Resource class should look like

```
sealed class Resource<T>(val data:T? = null,val message :String? = null,val state: Boolean) {

    class Success<T>(data:T,val state: Boolean):Resource<T>(data,state)
    class Error<T>(data: T?=null,message: String,val state: Boolean):Resource<T>(data,message,state)
    class Loading(val state: Boolean) : Resource(state)

}
```

```
viewModel.cartData.collect{
    setLoadingState(it.state)
       when(it){
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: There are numerous problems with this example. The child classes don’t override hashCode/equals. There are properties in the superclass that are not used in some of the subclasses. The Loading class has generics that it doesn’t use (you have to specify type when instantiating it when you shouldn’t have to). Ultimately, this class is worse than using a single non-sealed class with a property that uses the enum, because it has none of the benefits of being sealed and so it’s extra convolution with no advantage.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Please check the edited question where I added older Resource class which I want to convert to sealed class and whatever image I sent which I'm accessing in view / activity that is with older implementation.

Comment: You can't subclass `Resource` without specifying its generic type. For `Loading` you can make the generic type of `Resource` to be `Nothing` since you're not using it. Your code has compile errors too because you're shadowing final public properties of the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

You have `state: Boolean` in all of your cases, so it can be in defined in the sealed class or interface.

I prefer to use a sealed interface over sealed class unless there is really a need for some final function that works with the common property(ies).

`Loading` can be defined without a generic type since it doesn't have any `T` property. This makes it a little simpler to instantiate and work with.

```
sealed interface Resource<out T> {
    val state: Boolean

    data class Success<out T>(val data: T, val message: String, val code: Int, override val state: Boolean): Resource<T>
    data class Error<out T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String, val code: Int, override val state: Boolean): Resource<T>
    data class Loading(override val state: Boolean): Resource<Nothing>
}
```

Use `is` checks in your `when` statement when collecting these, as demonstrated in the [Kotlin documentation about sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes-and-when-expression).

It seems a little unusual to me that `Error` has a `data` property and that `Success` has a `message` property, but maybe it makes sense in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you not want to call Resource.Status.SUCCESS remove your enum from sealed class.

your current sealed class lookes like below

```
sealed class ResourceV2<out T> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T, val message: String, val code: Int, val state: Boolean) : ResourceV2<T>()
    data class Error<T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String, val code: Int, val state: Boolean) : ResourceV2<T>()
    data class Loading<T>(val state: Boolean) : ResourceV2<T>()
}
```

And access them in your view directly inside observer as below-

```
when (resource) {
    is ResourceV2.Success -> {
        val data = resource.data
        val message = resource.message
        val code = resource.code
        val state = resource.state
    }
    is ResourceV2.Error -> {
        val data = resource.data
        val message = resource.message
        val code = resource.code
        val state = resource.state
    }
    is ResourceV2.Loading -> {
        val state = resource.state
    }
}
```

For more details implementation follow https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow